# What's the difference between select distinct count, and select count distinct?

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I am aware of `select count(distinct a)`, but I recently came across `select distinct count(a)`.

I'm not very sure if that is even valid.

If it is a valid use, could you give me a sample code with a sample data, that would explain me the difference.

Hive doesn't allow the latter.

Any leads would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query `select count(distinct a)` will give you number of unique values in a.
While query `select distinct count(a)` will give you list of unique counts of values in a. Without grouping it will be just one line with total count.

See following example

```
create table t(a int)

insert into t values (1),(2),(3),(3)


select count (distinct a) from t

select distinct count (a) from t
group by a
```

It will give you `3` for first query and values `1` and `2` for second query.

Comment: Thanks @Marek. Makes sense with group by. No sense without it!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of any useful situation where you would want to use:

```
select distinct count(a)
```

If the query has no `group by`, then the `distinct` is anomalous.  The query only returns on row anyway.  If there is a `group by`, then the aggregation columns should be in the `select`, to identify each row.

I mean, technically, with a `group by`, it would be answering the question:  "how many different non-null values of `a` are in groups".  Usually, it is much more useful to know the value per group.

If you want to count the number of distinct values of `a`, then use `count(distinct a)`.

Comment: I though the same. But then I wasn't sure if there were any use cases without a grouping. thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you wanted a count of those values that have the same value, IE: duplicates.